# Problem on displaying that a string doesn't have a 6th character

Tags: java

I've been having trouble identifying the 6th character of two strings. So far, the code I have written displays the 6th character when both the strings have one. However, if they don't, the program crashes. Despite using boolean, it still hasn't properly worked. If someone could give some tips on how to fix it, it would be a huge help for a newbie like me. Thank you!

Here is the code (more specifically the method);

```
    //Method sixString
       public static void sixString() {
     boolean found = false;

    //The character at index 5 (6th character) of the first string is stored in p
    char p = str1.charAt(5);

    //The character at index 5 (6th character) of the second string is stored in q
    char q = str2.charAt(5);

    if (found == true) {
        //Display the 6th character of the first string
        System.out.println("The 6th character of the first string is: " + p);


        //Display the 6th character of the second string
        System.out.println("The 6th character of the second string is: " + q);
    }

    if (found == false) {
        //Display that there is no 6th character of the first string
        System.out.println(" Sorry! There is no 6th character in the first string ");

        //Display that there is no 6th character of the second string
        System.out.println(" Sorry! There is no 6th character in the second string ");
    }


//Method sixString()
}
```

1) If both strings have a 6th character, display the character in each string(this one is already completed)

2) If one string has a 6th character but the other doesn't, display the character for the string and a message to the user that the other string doesn't have (confused on this one; may need tips)

3) If both strings don't have one, display that they both don't have one (this is where the program crashes)

Comment: You never change the value of `found`. How is it supposed to determine if the length is 6 or more? (Also hint, there is a `length()` method in the `String` class)

Comment: `if (found == true) { ... } if (found == false) { ... }` can be simplified to `if (found) { ... } else {...}`.

Comment: That makes a lot more sense now. Thank you!

Comment: `str2.charAt(5)` will throw an `OutOfBoundsException` if the string is less that 6 characters in lenght. That is also on top of the fact that you don't change the `found` value at all.

Comment: In this code, program always runs only ```if (found == false)``` So, You need to change the ```boolean found``` by checking ```char p, q```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check the length of your input string before you call `.charAt()` with an index that is outside the bounds of the string, otherwise you will receive an exception.

```
if (str1.length() >= 6) {
    char p = str1.charAt(5);
    System.out.println("The 6th character of the first string is: " + p);
} else {
    System.out.println(" Sorry! There is no 6th character in the first string ");
}
```

Comment: This is what I truly needed. Your tip was simple and got the job done. Thank you!